# What's the difference between Ubuntu Studio and Xubuntu?

Tags: sound, xubuntu

Could anyone explain what's the difference between Ubuntu Studio and Xubuntu?(besides the preinstalled software).

Comment: The pre-installed software is the biggest difference. One has the `ubuntustudio-desktop` metapackage installed on top of an Ubuntu base, the other has a `xubuntu-desktop` metapackage installed on top of an Ubuntu base. If you have an hour or so, you can convert one into the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu Studio** is a recognized flavor of the Ubuntu Linux distribution, which is geared to general multimedia production. The original version, based on Ubuntu 7.04, was released on 10 May 2007[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio). These are Ubuntu Studio's main features:

> - **Low-latency kernel**:As of Ubuntu Studio 12.04, the default kernel is linux-lowlatency, which in essence is a generic Ubuntu Linux
>     kernel, with a tweaked configuration to allow for stable operation for
>     audio applications at lower latencies.
> - **Appearance and sound theme**:Ubuntu Studio also includes custom artwork and a blue-on-black theme, as opposed to Ubuntu's default
>     purple and orange. As with the main distribution of Ubuntu, if an
>     accelerated graphics card and appropriate driver are used, the
>     advanced desktop effects can be enabled.
> - **Access to Ubuntu repositories**: An important advantage of Ubuntu Studio over most other Linux distributions employing the real-time
>     kernel is access to the same repositories available to the main Ubuntu
>     distributions through the Update Manager, Synaptic Package Manager, as
>     well as through the Add/Remove Applications prompt.

**Xubuntu**  is a Canonical Ltd.–recognized, community-maintained derivative of the Ubuntu operating system. The name Xubuntu is a portmanteau of *Xfce* and *Ubuntu*, as it uses the Xfce desktop environment, instead of Ubuntu's GNOME desktop[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu). Xubuntu's goals are to:

> provide an easy to use distribution, based on Ubuntu, using Xfce as
>   the graphical desktop, with a focus on integration, usability and
>   performance, with a particular focus on low memory footprint. The
>   integration in Xubuntu is at a configuration level, a toolkit level,
>   and matching the underlying technology beneath the desktop in Ubuntu.
>   Xubuntu will be built and developed autonomously as part of the wider
>   Ubuntu community, based around the ideals and values of Ubuntu.

So, we come to the conclusion that Ubuntu Studio is a distribution, suitble for *multimedia production* while Xubuntu's foucus is to provide an environment which needs *low memory* and is highly *customizble*.